# show/filter some rows in a table

Tags: jquery, html-table, rows

I'm trying to show only some row of my table generated by the following code (for example only two):

```
function loadTable(){

    $.getJSON( 'sort.php', function( data ) {
        $('#mytable tbody tr').remove();
        $.each( data, function( i, val ) {
            $('#mytable tbody').append('<tr><td>'+val.value0+'</td><td>'+val.value1+'</td><td>'+val.value2+'kb/'+val.value3+'kb</td><td>10:59 08/01/2014</td></tr>');
        });
    });

    $('#mytable tbody').hide();
    $('#mytable tr').slice(0, 2).show();
    setTimeout("loadTable()",15000);
  }
```

but with this code works only the hide function and not the show. any help?

Comment: Dont you need to show it in the ajax success callback? Because you are hiding your tbody before that.

Comment: donot hide the parent it will hide the child's also.. just hide those rows which u want .. rest is default are show.

Comment: removing the hide of tbody, I have tried to show some rows but I didn't succeed too. Please Can You show me the way with an example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not show rows until they are added to the page.

```
function loadTable(){

    var tbody = $('#mytable tbody').hide();

    $.getJSON( 'sort.php', function( data ) {
        tbody.empty();
        $.each( data, function( i, val ) {
            tbody.append('<tr><td>'+val.value0+'</td><td>'+val.value1+'</td><td>'+val.value2+'kb/'+val.value3+'kb</td><td>10:59 08/01/2014</td></tr>');
        });

        tbody.find("tr").hide().slice(0, 2).show();
        tbody.show();
        setTimeout(loadTable,15000);


    });

  }
```

Comment: I added code to "hide" the extra rows. Not sure if that was the issue.

Comment: What does not work? It does not give me any information to fix it. Is there an error in console? Does the browser catch on fire
?

Comment: it still shows all the rows without make a filtering of the first 2 rows

Comment: It is supposed to show the first two rows or hide the first two?

Comment: I would like to show the first n-number of rows of my table (i.e. n=2)

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/zygLU/ Looks fine to me, I removed the getJSON code and just put in a hard coded array of objects. I am not sure what you are doing different.

Comment: I have tried copying your code as it is on mine and it worked. May be it was my mistyping, sorry for that. I'll double check what I did wrong. Thank you very much for your help

Answer (score 0):

The problem may be that you are hiding the parent and then trying to show the child.

```
$('#mytable tbody').hide();
$('#mytable tr').slice(0, 2).show();
```

Instead, just hide the child rows you don't want to show.

```
$('#mytable tr').slice(2, $('#mytable tr').length).hide();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/B8MzM/